# Unable to Right aligning elements print statement in loop

Tags: python

So I have the following lists:

```
population = [60000, 120000, 200000, 5000]
```

Want to format the output as such:

```
Lo: loc_pop
-----------
1     60000
2    120000
3    200000
4      5000
```

The issue that I am having is that I am unable to right align the print statement so that all the values of population (regardless of size) align in the manner I displayed above.

Here is the code:

```
population = [123100, 60000, 98300, 220000, 5000]

print("Lo: loc_pop")
print("-----------")
count = 0
for x in range(0, len(population)):
    print(count, ":", " ", population[x])
    count = count + 1
```

Here is the output:

```
Lo: loc_pop
-----------
0 :   123100
1 :   60000
2 :   98300
3 :   220000
4 :   5000
```

The output seems to add a space after the "count" and before the ":", and depending on the number of digits, it is not properly right aligned.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) in Python to format your strings. Also, `count` variable is not required in your code because you can get value directly from looping variable.

```
population = [123100, 60000, 98300, 220000, 5000]

print("Lo: loc_pop")
print("-----------")

for x in range(0, len(population)):
    print('{}{:>10}'.format(x+1, population[x]))

# Lo: loc_pop 
# ----------- 
# 1     60000 
# 2    120000 
# 3    200000 
# 4      5000
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print in the specify format, this is enough, using [rjust](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust):

```
population = [60000, 120000, 200000, 5000]
header = "Lo: loc_pop"
header_length = len(header)

print(header)
print("-" * header_length)
for i, p in enumerate(population, 1):
    print(i, str(p).rjust(header_length - (len(str(i)) + 1)))
```

**Output**

```
Lo: loc_pop
-----------
1     60000
2    120000
3    200000
4      5000
```

However if you are planning on doing additional stuff, related to data, I suggest you take a look at [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution is probably to use pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'loc_pop': [60000, 120000, 200000, 5000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
```

Result:

```
   loc_pop
0    60000
1   120000
2   200000
3     5000
```